# Añadir muchos elementos a array - Kotlin

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin

Tengo una función que recibe muchos parámetros, luego añado esos parámetros a un array, la función es una JavaScriptInterface, que obtiene datos de la pagina que visita, x ello no puedo recibir un array, ya que solo acepta datos primitivos.

```
 @JavascriptInterface
        fun getDataState(c1I1T: String,c1I1S: String,c1I1I: String,c1I1U: String,c1I2T: String,...) {
          
                Varss.pContent1.add(c1I1T)
                Varss.pContent1.add(c1I1S)
                Varss.pContent1.add(c1I1I)
                .....
                ..... 

        }
```

**Habría forma de simplificar eso, a algo como**

```
 @JavascriptInterface
        fun getDataState(String:c1I1S, c1I1I,c1I1U,c1I2T,c1I2S...) {
        
                Varss.pContent1.add(c1I1S,c1I1I,c1I1U,c1I2T,c1I2S..)

            }
```

O talvez a algo parecido.

Comment: Varss.pContent1 es un array verdad?

Comment: es un  un arrayListOf<String>()

Comment: @Redox arrayListOf<T> no es un objeto es un método que devuelve un ArrayList<T>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes usar la funcion `arrayOf()` en lugar de `add()` , ejemplo:

```
   @JavascriptInterface
  fun getDataState(c1I1T: String,c1I1S: String,c1I1I: String,c1I1U: String,c1I2T: String) {

        Varss.pContent1 = arrayOf(c1I1T, c1I1S,c1I1I,c1I1U,c1I2T);

      
    }
```

---

Actualización:

Comentas que estas usando `arrayListOf<String>()`, en este caso puedes usar `arrayListOf()` :

```
   @JavascriptInterface
  fun getDataState(c1I1T: String,c1I1S: String,c1I1I: String,c1I1U: String,c1I2T: String) {

        Varss.pContent1 = arrayListOf(c1I1T, c1I1S,c1I1I,c1I1U,c1I2T);

      
    }
```

Comment: Es justo lo que deseo sin embargo tengo un arrayListOf<String>() y aquí no funciona. Existe un arrayOf() para eso.

Comment: Varss.pContent1 = arrayListOf(c1I1T, c1I1T,......) , esto funciona.

Comment: Si usas arrayListOf<String>() entonces debes usar arrayListOf(), actualicé la respuesta. @Redox

Answer (score 1):

por supuesto podrias hacer que `c1I1` sea un parámetro ilimitado y luego asignarlo a `Varss.pContent1`:

```
fun getDataState(vararg c1I1: String){
   Varss.pContent1 = c1I1.asList()
}
```

solo se debe usar la palabra reservada `vararg` que en este caso convertirá el parámetro en un `Array<String>`

Comment: lo único que me desconcertar es porque la función se llama getDataState si lo que hace es insertar, los nombres deben ser preferiblemente nominales o descriptivos XD

Comment: Lo acabo de probar, funciona perfecto, pero solo para Array verdad, con un arrayListOf no es posible?

Comment: cambiare el nombre de mi función XD

Comment: @Redox la unica es hacer una conversion con `Arrays.asList()` que convierte los arrays a listas

Comment: @Redox en kotlin solo hay que hacer `c1I1.asList()`